# How to set right version of php on linux

Tags: php, linux

Our system currently has multiple versions of php installed. the apache server is configured to use the latested version(5.3). but when i log in, i still get the older version php. how can i configure my own environment to use the right version php?

Thanks,

Comment: You question is too localized - we don't know your environment. You could rephrase and enhance your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

1. Modify the PATH so that includes the correct PHP-directory. See [this](http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/prepostpath.htm).
2. Set up an alias for the new PHP version. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28command%29).

> ```
> alias php53="/path/to/php5.3/bin/php"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely more for superuser.com, but you can modify `.bash_rc` and alias `PHP` to <whatever your path is for PHP>